# Meaning of symbol F1 (or Fl) in formula

Tags: notation

In OEIS sequence [A008949](http://oeis.org/A008949) one have formula
$T(n,k) = \textrm {binomial}(n,n-k)* 2F1(1, -k; n+1-k)(-1)$
What does symbol $F1$ (or $Fl$) mean in it?

Comment: It's ${}_2F_1(a,b;c,x)$ -- a *hypergeometric function*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should read $$T(n,k)={n \choose k}\;_2F_1(1,-k;n+1-k;-1)$$ but an equivalent formula is $$T(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^k{n \choose i}$$
where $k<=n$ and zero if $k>n$.